# clearInterval won't clear the interval in background change script

Tags: javascript, jquery, clearinterval

I have this small script that changes the background image with a fadein/out effect:

```
/*controla la velocidad de la animación*/
    var slideshowSpeed = 1000;
    var transitionSpeed = 2000;
    var timeoutSpeed = 500;
    
    /*No tocar*/
    var interval;
    var activeContainer = 1;    
    var currentImg = 0;
    var animating = false;
    var navigate = function(direction) {
        // Si ya estamos navegando, entonces no hacemos nada!
        if(animating) {
            return;
        }
        currentImg++;
        if(currentImg == photos.length + 1) {
            currentImg = 1;
        }
        // Tenemos dos, uno en el que tenemos la imagen que se ve y otro d?nde tenemos la imagen siguiente
        var currentContainer = activeContainer;
        // Esto puedo optimizarlo con la funci?n modulo, y cambiar 1 y 2 por 0 y 1-> active = mod2(active + 1)
        if(activeContainer == 1) {
            activeContainer = 2;
        } else {
            activeContainer = 1;
        }
        // hay que decrementar el ?ndice porque empieza por cero
        cargarImagen(photos[currentImg - 1], currentContainer, activeContainer);
    };
    var currentZindex = -1;
    var cargarImagen = function(photoObject, currentContainer, activeContainer) {
        animating = true;
        // Nos aseguramos que el nuevo contenedor está siempre dentro del cajon
        currentZindex--;
        /*if(currentZindex < 0) currentZindex=1;*/
        // Actualizar la imagen
        $("#headerimg" + activeContainer).css({
            "background-image" : "url(" + photoObject + ")",
            "display" : "block",
            "z-index" : currentZindex
        });
        // FadeOut antigua
        // Cuando la transición se ha completado, mostramos el header 
        $("#headerimg" + currentContainer).fadeOut(transitionSpeed,function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                
                animating = false;
            }, timeoutSpeed);
        });
    };
    
function iniciarPase(){
    var animating = false;
    //ver la siguente
     navigate("next");
    //iniciar temporizador que mostrará las siguientes
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        navigate("next");
    }, slideshowSpeed);
}
function pararPase(){
    var animating = true;
    console.log('paramos la animación');
    interval = clearInterval(interval);
}
/*Gestion de pase de imágenes de fondo*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    iniciarPase();
});
```

But the function `pararPase()` which contains the `clearInterval` expression seems not to work even if its on the `<body onload="pararPase()">`

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: your not calling `pararPase` anywhere ... and `var animating =` in the start / stop methods is doing nothing !!!!

Comment: What's the value of `interval` in the `pararPase()`? I suspect this is some scoping or timing issue (that is, `interval` doesn't have value you think it does)

Comment: When you say pararPase doesn't work do you mean it isn't getting called at all? I certainly notice you don't seem to be calling it anywhere at the moment... Do you want to show the code where it is getting called as well?

Comment: `interval = clearInterval(interval);` should be only `clearInterval(interval);`

Comment: where `var interval;` is written - is this within a function ? all of your "global" code seems to be indented indicating it might all be within a function ? ie making it not global !

Comment: Why are you assigning `interval = clearInterval(interval)`? Just curious - I've never seen a var assignment on a `clearInterval`, only on `setInterval`.

Comment: From jQuery [ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) documentation: The `.ready()` method is generally incompatible with the `<body onload="">` attribute. ... use jQuery's .load() method to attach load event handlers to the window ...

Comment: @ManseUK well not in the question but i am in my code and its not doing anythig (but it logs the console.log); also, if i remove the asignment and leave only clearInterval(interval) i get same problem. intervall is not cleared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your base logic is working just fine, here is [live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/nWSAv/).

So most likely you bind `pararPase` incorrectly, for example trying to bind as click handler outside `document.ready()` when the button does not yet exist - [updated test case](http://jsfiddle.net/nWSAv/1/) to prove this point.

Another option is other error in your code, check Chrome JavaScript console to see if this is the case.

As others mentioned in comments, assigning the return value of clearInterval back to the variable is meaningless, but not harmful: the variable will just have the value "undefined".

**Edit**: there is a chance that `iniciarPase` is called more than once, this will cause more than one timers where only the last will be cleared. So, to be on the safe side add this to your function: (that's actually what Diode tried to say in his answer)

```
function iniciarPase(){
    var animating = false;
    //ver la siguente
    navigate("next");
    //iniciar temporizador que mostrará las siguientes
    if (interval)
        clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        navigate("next");
    }, slideshowSpeed);
}
```

Comment: that's basically what i am doning.. i have a something like $('.stop').click(pararPase) but won't work (i would see the console.log but the interval wont clear)

Comment: @Toni so this means `iniciarPase` is called more than once. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
clearInterval(interval);
interval = setInterval(function() {
   navigate("next");
}, slideshowSpeed);
```